What is the benefit of letting FastAPI handle SQLAlchemy's session vs the provided context manager?
I am doing a POC on FastAPI with a Controller-Service-Repository architecture. Service and Repository are classes, with dependency injection done in the __init__ function like so:
(This is the architecture, above my paygrade)
Class MyService(IService):
    def __init__(self, repository):
        self.repository = MyRepository() # Dependency Injection
        ...

Class MyRepository(IRepository):
    def __init__(self):
        ... # May create Engine and Session

I've been following FastApi's documentation on Relational Database, and this block of code is suggested:
# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

This creates a fresh sqlalchemy session when called and closes the session when the request ends, to be injected to the path operator function so that we get a fresh session per request.
According to this answer by the creator of SQLAlchemy:

[T]he question is, what's the difference between making a new Session() at various points versus just using one all the way through. The answer, not very much.

and

This practice (one session per request) ensures that the new request begins "clean". If some objects from the previous request haven't been garbage collected yet, and if maybe you've turned off "expire_on_commit", maybe some state from the previous request is still hanging around, and that state might even be pretty old. If you're careful to leave expire_on_commit turned on and to definitely call commit() or rollback() at request end, then it's fine, but if you start with a brand new Session, then there's not even any question that you're starting clean.

Per my understanding, FastAPI's one-session-per-request is not necessary if we use SQLAlchemy's defaults and context managers, like so:
# create session and add objects
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(some_object)
    session.add(some_other_object)
    session.commit()

By using FastAPI's one-session-per-request, a new MyService instance and/or MyRepository instance is created for each request. FastApi docs says that dependencies are "cached" and reused only in the same request. However, if we stick with SQLAlchemy's doc, we can make my MyService and MyRepository singletons.
What is the benefit of letting FastAPI handle SQLAlchemy's session vs the provided context manager?
Is the overheads of creating instances per request negligible? Is there something with asyncio that I'm unaware of? Something to do with threads or process, or FastAPI's implementation?

Most web applications can expect to be serving parallel requests. Sharing a session (a single database connection) in this context is likely to result in some hard to manage behaviour, if not outright errors.

And I'd guess that issuing a commit in one of the running coroutines (under async programming) will suddenly commit anything in your session, so a later rollback won't work as you expect it to.

When you use one session per request, it blocks the connection to the database until the request is finished. Moreover, when you are using a connection pool with limited connections, it might lead to a situation where you are left with no available connections. Some API calls can include logic outside of working with the database, so there is no need to keep the connection locked all this time. This approach may work in small applications, but in larger ones with a lot of incoming requests, it might lead to issues.

I have phrased the question incorrectly. It should be: why let FastAPI handle the session with DI instead of using SQLAlchemy's context manager.
AFAIK, Engine is a connection pool, and with Session(engine) as session requests a connection from the pool when needed, and returns the connection to the pool when exited. SQLAlchemy's implementation is not one-session-for everything.

Edited. Also my comment addresses the other comments about connection blocking or reusing sessions. It's typically not a problem when using SQLAlchemy's session context manager.

What is the benefit of letting FastAPI handle SQLAlchemy's session vs the provided context manager?
To my mind, the benefits are convenience and safety.

FastAPI already provides the tools for managing database sessions, so using those tools allows us to focus on delivering business value*.
We can assume that the developers of FastAPI have thought about their architecture, and implemented it in a way that avoids common traps around concurrency and transaction handling and "goes with the grain" of the framework.

You are free to implement you own session management system, if you  want, or to use SQLAlchemy's default context manager capabilities, but I'd recommend reading When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it? and Contextual/Thread-local Sessions
... we can make my MyService and MyRepository singletons
Do this if you must but read the two links above. In particular, make sure you create a new session for each request.

* Boring, but that's what most of us get paid for, most of the time.

My working theory is (1) FastAPI wanted to demonstrate DI with yeild, (2) their example only has two layers, and (3) the Session object should not be handled in the repository class. As such, the only reasonable place is to DI it into the controller. But I wanted to hear what more experienced people has to say about this.

(1) Assuming you mean yield, this is a fairly common pattern (for example, pytest fixtures) (2) I haven't used FastAPI extensively, but I would tend to agree (3) Names like IService and IRepository suggest an architecture influenced by languages other than Python, for better or worse. You might be interested in reading the Cosmic Python book, which addresses similar issues.

My current implementation has the repository expose a repo.get_session() method that returns a fresh session from sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker. The service will obtain a fresh session this way, and manage this session with sqlalchemy's context manager. The controller is then injected the service, which has the repository injected all via FastApi Depends method.  With this implementation, both service and repository can be singletons and no new object instances need to be created per request. I think this addresses everything you've brought up, but do highlight if I missed something!

Ah yes, I came from javaland, I'm not a python purist. I think of myself as realist. Whether to use "code-to-interface" pattern is a bit out of scope for this post. Briefly, I think it has its place in certain situations. For my case, I don't know what libraries would be approved post-POC. If there are changes, I'd only need to implement the correct interface instead of rewiring the entire application.
